# How to simplify this integrand,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to compute arc length in three dimensions but am currently stuck with integrating $$\sqrt{1+ e^{-2t} + 4e^{-2t}}$$

Can I get some hints on how to simplify?

I didn't combine the second and third terms, because I was hoping to arrive at some trig identity such as $1+\sinh^2(t) = \cosh^2(t)$.

Substitution methods are problematic, too, with the exponential function.

Also, completing the square doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks,

Comment: At first you might want to note that $e^{-2t}+4e^{-2t}=5e^{-2t}$.

Comment: Substitute twice, firstly $u=e^{-t}$ and secondly $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} sinh(u)$.

Comment: Hi @ThomasE., if I did combine the second and third terms, where can I go from here?  Rubertos' substitution would be too clever for me to get on my own, so I was wondering whether there is another way - thanks,

Comment: Thanks @Rubertos - I'll try this out now.  I substituted twice also, but not the way you had suggested.  What's the intuition for the 1/sqrt(5) factor?

Comment: @LebronJames To remove the coefficient $5$ at $5e^{-t}$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: substitute $${ { e } }^{ -t }=\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 5 }  } \tan { x }$$

Comment: @1999: it is an excellent hint, which is what was requested. $\sqrt5e^{-t}=\sinh(u)$ is another hint which leads to a solution.

Comment: Hi @Nemo, I am struggling a little bit with how to replace the dt term.  Should I treat $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} tan(x)$ as "u" and compute du/dt?  That gives du = $e^{-t}(-1)$dt => $\frac{-du \sqrt(5)}{tanx}$ = dt, I think.  So, I'm getting an integrand that is just csc(x), with a -$\sqrt{5}$ factor.

Comment: hi,i have done it,i will try write here

Comment: $\Rightarrow$ $$t=-\ln { \left( \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 5 }  } tanx \right)  } $$ $\Rightarrow $ $$dt=-\frac { \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 5 }  } \frac { 1 }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 5 }  } tanx } dx=-\frac { 1 }{ sinxcosx } dx$$ $$\int { \sqrt { 1+5{ e }^{ -2t } } dt } =-\int { \sqrt { 1+{ tan }^{ 2 }x }  } \frac { dx }{ sinxcox } =\int { \frac { dx }{ { cos }^{ 2 }x\quad sinx }  } $$
i think you can come up with last one,or not?

Comment: Hi @robjohn, does the formula for arc length, integration of $\sqrt{(x'(t))^2 + (y'(t))^2 + (z'(t))^2}$, hold for other coordinate systems, such as cylindrical coordinates, meaning can I compute the integral of  $\sqrt{(r'(t))^2 + (\theta'(t))^2 + (z'(t))^2}$ to get the arc length of a curve in 3-D that is parametrized in cylindrical coordinates?  Or, I must first convert r(t), $\theta(t)$ and z(t) to x, y, z coordinates, before applying the formula?

Comment: FYI, I've posted my comment as a new question on MSE - thanks, @robjohn.

Comment: Thanks @Nemo - I think I may be headed in the wrong direction and should stop, actually.  I think I should first convert from cylindrical to rectangular coordinates, with parameter t - then apply the usual arc length formula.  Maybe I should have posted the full question :-(